# How to deploy a codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new on this kind of stuffs, so excuse my ignorance. The thing is I've built an app with codeigniter and now that I'm done I'd like to know how i can deploy it onto a server. It's the first time with something like that

I'd like to put it in my own server, because it will be used as a backend for the people I work with. But i am clueless about how it should be done.

I also have the project in a git repository so I wonder if i can deploy it easily from there. I read about using Phing, but I didn't find a 'step-by-step' tutorial to follow.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Install Apache, PHP, MySQL. Configure vhosts in Apache, make SQL user and database, deploy files to vhost DocumentRoot. Win?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So it's just installing apache, php and mysql in my server and then copy the whole projecto folder and it will work?

Comment: As long as apache & php is configured correctly, yes.

Comment: http://12devsofxmas.co.uk/2013/01/day-9-deploy-your-projects-with-git/

Comment: but do i need to pay for a hosting for do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally did it! As @Jono20201 said it was all about placing the whole project correctly.

> Install Apache, PHP, MySQL. Configure vhosts in Apache, make SQL user and database, deploy files to vhost DocumentRoot. Win?

I tried with a free hosting service (hostinger). I uploaded the files and made a few changes and it worked!

Important changes I made:

1. The project directory tree should look like this:

```text
 ROOT
 ├── Applications(Controllers, models, views, etc.)
 ├── System
 └── public_html
```

`public_html` should contain `index.php`, `assets` with `css` and `js` files and `.htaccces` that should look like this if you want to get rid of the `index.php` thing in the routing)

2. Modify `.htaccess` file. Example:

```conf
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

3. Once you have those files place, you have to rewrite the `config.php`, `database.php` and `route.php` files with the new parameters.

And that's it! Hope i help someone that is as lost as I was!

I also modified the `index.php` file which is placed in `public_html`:

- I added `$system_path = '../system';`
- I added `$application_folder = '../application';`

Answer (score 1):

For code igniter4  hosting is little tricky as folder structure changed from previous version. [See ansewer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808444/how-to-host-codeigniter4-website-on-sharehosting)

Answer (score 0):

If you have simple Linux based Web Hosting plan, then just copy your files to your server's root and configure you db using phpmyadmin.

You are all set to use your app. It is not like WP where you need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the problem with the deficient tutorial on the codeigniter site. The problem was with routes.php where the controller names were lowercase, but moving to a Linux hosting, there the case matters so I had to rename. In general, naming convention sucks in that tutorial...