# How to host codeigniter4 website on sharehosting?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I have just created a codeigniter4 project and I want to upload it on sharehosting. But my website is not accesible, it gives server error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  You'll need to share more specific details about the problem for anyone to be able to help.  Edit your question, and add the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For security reason codeigniter4 folder is made suchg a way that all the libraried and code folder is outside the public folder. By url only public folder is accesible.
To host it on share hosting your directory structure should look like this.

```
--home/root (sharehosting root directory)
   |__ public_html (or your domain root folder)
   |    |__assets
   |    |__ index.php
   |    |__ .htaccess
   |
   |__ codeigniter (create a folder with any name you like)
        |__ app(all the files and folder in app folder)
        |__ system
        |__ writable
        |__ .env (dot env file here)
```

Now you need to change some values to up and running your codeigniter4 project

- In `public_html` folder `index.php` file chnage the `$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';` to `$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../codeigniter/app/Config/Paths.php';`
- In `app/Config` folder `App.php` file change `$baseURL = 'http://192.168.0.111/';` to  `$baseURL = 'http://yourdomain.com/';`.

After this chnage your site will be up and running.
To deploy in subdomain and if your subdomain root folder lies in public_html then you should change `$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';` to `$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../../codeigniter/app/Config/Paths.php';` in `public_html/yourdomain` folder `index.php` file, followed that directory structure remains same. **Important**: public folder content should be placed in your subdomain folder.

Comment: Thanks, its usefull details for hosting in shared hosting

Comment: I have done the same thing but in different way- keeping the whole contents of CI4 App in a separte sub-directory at shared hosting's public_html folder- Pls see the details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059842/3618632