# Codeigniter 4 works fine local but online production server gives a error: CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

When uploaded on the server

```
/app
/public_html
/vendor
/writable
```

And use https://server.com/home I see the welcome page but when I user https://server.com/pages I get a error 'CodeIgniter\View\Exceptions\ViewException
Invalid file: pages/home.php' **SYSTEMPATH/Exceptions/FrameworkException.php at line 21**

```
 public static function forEnabledZlibOutputCompression()
15   {
16   return new static(lang('Core.enabledZlibOutputCompression'));
17   }
18 
19  public static function forInvalidFile(string $path)
20   {
21  return new static(lang('Core.invalidFile', [$path]));
22   }
23 
24  public static function forCopyError(string $path)
25     {
26         return new static(lang('Core.copyError', [$path]));
27     }
28
```

Comment: Please post your route code if any and your controller where you call ``pages`` in order to get clear explanation of your error. I think I will be able to help you

Comment: I solved the problem. Het has to do with capitals, typo fault (Pages instead of pages directory name) in the folder system. Mac can handle this but on the linux server it results in a error

Comment: okay nice you have found solution to your problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61808799/11024771

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('users/signin',$data);

<?= $this->extend('layouts/signin') ?>
```

It is Slash issue caused , I had same issue before and now all is well